# Pyside2 WebEngine html-select very slowly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2, qtwebengine

I am working with pyside2 5.14, using QWebEngine to render html GUI. Work is going under Windows 10.

My `main.py`

```py
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWebEngine import QtWebEngine
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts)

QtWebEngine.initialize()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

view = QWebEngineView()
view.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(QDir.current().filePath("index.html")))
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and `index.html`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<select>
    <option value="1">v1</option>
    <option value="2">v2</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I discovered some bug with select html-control. After second click on select, menu disappears for 2-3 sec and application blocks for that time. Has anyone solved a similar problem?

Comment: It seems a bug since in Linux I do not observe that problem, report it.

Comment: I tested on Linux, and it works well, current problem under Windows 10. PySide 5.14 and Python 3.7.1